# Sounds from Tajikistan or the countries around.

Tags: sound-effects

I'm working on a documentary on Tajikistan. I'm looking for sound banks or recordings from the region for ambiences and specs. Any good leads?

Answer (score 3):

So, since it's a documentary, I guess you should apply a little effort and try to get a true recordings of Tajikistan and not from "the countries around". Or it will be some sort of a careless work :)

There is a large Russian music maker forum:
http://forum.rmmedia.ru/forum.php
It's in Russian language only, but it's very popular place on the former USSR countries also (accordingly, in Tajikistan).

You can create an account there and put your message and maybe you will be lucky and you will find some studios who will be able to record or sell to you some audio material or maybe give you some sort of advice.

Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

Try Sounddogs.com, Rob Nokes has done some recording around there. [Here's](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DzUcuOMWrI8&list=UUaKW0Jj1oOwTnvf2t9Apbmw&index=18&feature=plcp) a video.

Comment: +1 Aside from buying out the whole BBC library, this is probably the best viable option I can think of.